# How do I put an HTML page to be displayed when opening a website from hosts file?

Tags: security, internet, hosts

Hosts file is blocking access to some websites. How do i put custom HTML instead of default message "This site can’t be reached"?

Comment: If you are just forwarding these websites to localhost (127.0.0.1), you can use some software like apache2 to put an HTML in localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has nothing to do with the other.

A `hosts` file is just a "directory" of host names and their IP addresses.  It's not limited to websites.  You can think of it as a "flat file DNS lookup."

```
# Sample hosts file
#

123.456.789.001      foo.bar
```

With this address, you can...

- Go to a website - http://foo.bar
- SMB share :  smb://foo.bar
- SSH connection:  `ssh user@foo.bar`
- Copy files securely from one host to another - `scp stuff.ext user@foo.bar:/path/stuff`
- and much more

In order for your browser to display a web page, it must be "served" that page.  Since, by default, your clients aren't running a web server, there's nothing to serve.

I'm assuming that you want to display this "web page" when someone goes to a site you "blocked" by using a custom `hosts` file.

You need to do this at the (your) network level where the DNS lookup redirects (or firewall intercepts/redirects) to a server hosting your error page.